# Create "Brands" category using Wordpress WooCommerce plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

For my e-commerce site I'm trying to implement product "Brands", say Samsung, Nokia etc for each product. I want to create a new *category* type "Brands" & one product can be assigned to only one "Brands" category.

Products are implemented by a custom post-type called "Products" by WooCommere plug-in.

I'm using [woocommerce](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/) plug-in. This plug-in already has a "product category" option that allows products to be assigned to categories, I want to keep it intact, because I want to have different product categories like "electronics", "clothes", "household" etc. Keeping this category intact, I want to create a new category type called "Brands" which will be applicable to products.

Any Idea on how I can write a plug-in to create a custom category called "Brands" and display it in the "Create new Product" admin page *(typical wordpress admin page for creating new post)*? I also want to restrict one product to one category only.

I'm new to Wordpress so your suggestion will be extremely helpful to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have started using a WooCommerce extension called Brand, which does what you are after.
While I am having a couple of issues with it, it gives me the ability to list products by their brand name and has several widgets and shortcodes.

See it at my [paper craft site](http://charlotteswebpapercraft.com.au) in the left menu